# Conditional Probability of Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, bayes-theorem

**Question:** Suppose that the length of a phone call in minutes is an exponential random variable with
parameter λ =1/8.If someone arrives immediately ahead of you at a public telephone booth, find the probability that

**A)** you will have to wait more than 5 minutes.

**C)** If you have waited for 5 minutes, what is the probability that you will have to wait more
than 15 minutes in total?

**My Solution (for A):** `P(X > 5) = e^-5/8 = 0.53`

**My Solution (for C):** `P(X > 10 | X >= 5) = P(X > 10 AND X >= 5) / P(X >= 5)`

Using Bayes Rule,

```
= ( P(X >= 5 | X > 10) * P(> 10) ) / P(X >= 5)
= P(X > 10) / P(X >= 5)
```

Using exponential random variable rule: `P(X > x) = e^(-λx)`

```
= (e^-10/8) / (e^-5/8)
= 0.53
```

**My Issue:** I am not sure if I am using the correct equation for P(X >= 5). I don't understand how the probabilities can be the same after a condition has been placed.

I don't understand how you could have the same probability after a condition has been placed. 
**Can you please help find an issue with my logic?**

Comment: Just a note, $P(X=5)$ makes no sense here. $X$ is a continuous random variable, so $P(X=5)=0$.

Comment: Funny thing is, I didn't even notice that initially you had written `P = 5` when it should have been `P >= 5`. That's partly because you did write `P >= 5` in the initial formulation of conditional probability; it's also because the formulas are not as easy to read in "programming" notation as they are in standard math notation. You can write standard math notation here using MathJax; a starting point to learn it is https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ so in special case $A\subseteq B$ we wil get $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)=P(A)/P(B)$. Apply that on $A=\{X>15\}$ and $B=\{X>5\}$.

Comment: @DavidK I overlooked that too by first reading.

Comment: @DavidK - Thanks for the link - I was wondering how people posted in math notation on here. I am in Comp Sci, so I am used to the programming notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $P(X > 10 \mid X \geq 5)$ does not do what you apparently think it does. The variable $X$ has to represent the same thing in both places where it occurs in this formula. 
If you keep using the definition from part A, then $X$ is the total amount of time you wait from the moment you arrive until you are able to make your call, in which case the condition in part C is that $X \geq 5$ and the event "you will have to wait more than $15$ minutes in total" is $X > 15.$
The event $X > 10$ would be "you have to wait more than $10$ minutes in total."

You seem to want $X > 10$ to be the probability that you wait an *additional* ten minutes. But that's redefining what $X$ is from the definition you used in part A.
If you redefine $X$ in this way, then $X$ is really "total waiting time minus $5$ minutes," and the condition that you have waited at least $5$ minutes becomes $X \geq 0$.

So what you calculated is actually the probability that you have to wait an additional **five** minutes given that you already waited five minutes.
And an interesting property of an exponential distribution for a waiting time is that it has no "memory": no matter how long you wait, the conditional probability of waiting another $N$ minutes is the same as the initial probability that you would wait $N$ minutes.

Comment: Okay, yes I see how I mistakenly redefined the random variable X. Thanks for pointing this out. 

For the second part, the property you are mentioning is something like: P(X > a | X > b) (where b < a) is always going to just be P(X > a) ?

Comment: If $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0,$ The "no memory" property is actually $P(X > a + b \mid X > b) = P(X > a).$ So when you wrote $P(X > 10 \mid X\geq 5),$ we can put $a = b = 5$ and see that this conditional probability is equal to $P(X > 5).$ (Note that whether we write $X>k$ or $X\geq k$ makes no difference here since the probability of an exact match is always zero.)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution for A) is correct.

For C) you have tried to calculate the probability that you will have to wait more than $10$ minutes in total.

You could do so by stating that: $$P(X>10\mid X>5)=P(X>10\wedge X>5)/P(X>5)=P(X>10)/P(X>5)=e^{-\frac58}$$

No rule of Bayes is applied.

You were asked however to find the probability on waitinb $15$ minutes in total:
$$P(X>15\mid X>5)=P(X>10)=e^{-\frac{10}8}$$

The exponential distribution is [memoryless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) (which is nicely illustrated by the former calculation where it is actually shown that $P(X>10\mid X>5)=P(X>5)$). I make use of that fact.